# How should I handle removed elements in JSoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am working on an application that requires removal of Elements from document.

```
for(Element d : doc.getAllElements()){

if(condition){
 d.getAllElements().remove();
 }

}
```

On Doing this, I am constantly getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object must not be null
```

So far, I have checked various null conditions, like if(d != null) etc, but none seems working. Can you please suggest what should be the solution?

Update : 
Suppose I have two loops in which I am removing Elements upon satisfaction of a condition. 
Code below is just for example, please do not suggest workarounds on this, like break the loop on first condition etc, I need to understand it at logical level.

```
for(Element e: doc.getAllElements()){

if(condition1 == true)
{
e.getAllElements().remove();

}


if(condition2 == true){

e.getAllElements().remove();

}


}
```

If both conditions satisfy, elements get deleted in first loop, and when it comes to second condition, it throws illegal exception. I tried to evaluate the problem and found that JSoup internally checks if the element is not null, and if it is, it throws and exception. Consider the scene :

```
if(e != null) // e is an Element.
```

In the above null check, JSoup checks the existence of e, which is null in this case, and hence and exception, before coming to next words != null. I checked documentation and found there is a method existing Validation.notNull(Element), but it returns void. Is it possible to get a boolean return value from this? What else is the solution?

Comment: What's the line? Show the full stack trace.

Comment: ya, I have checked, it is the same line, whenever I try d.(somemethod), it throws the same exception, because it is already removed in some previous loop.

Comment: Give more code. It's a bit hard to understand the problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the results of doc.getAllElements(), you'll see that the first element is the entire document, because technically, the `<html></html>` is a single element. If you try to .remove() this element, it has no parent, so you get this null error when it tries to validate that the parent exists.

If you just want to remove stuff from the body, I suggest using

```
for(Element e: doc.select('body'))
```

or similar if you don't just want the body

Comment: Please note, the problem is with two loops with different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the element is still present inside the document, then remove it. Remove elements one-by-one:

```
for (Element element: doc.getAllElements()) {
    if(condition1 == true)
    {
        for (Element subElement: element.getAllElements()) {
            if (subElement.root() == doc) {
                subElement.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    if(condition2 == true)
    {
        for (Element subElement: element.getAllElements()) {
            if (subElement.root() == doc) {
                subElement.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you remove any element from jsoup document then it's reference becomes null. Hence you have to put null checks wherever you use 'remove'.

Comment: That's incorrect. The element reference does not change upon removal.